# How to optimise paging in SQL Server when you order by a non indexed field

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have read and followed instructions here:
[What is an efficient method of paging through very large result sets in SQL Server 2005?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/169596/what-is-an-efficient-method-of-paging-through-very-large-result-sets-in-sql-serv) and what becomes clear is I'm ordering by a non-indexed field - this is because it's a generated field from calcuations - it does not exist in the database.

I'm using the row_number() technique and it works pretty well.  My problem is that my stored procedure does some pretty big joins on a fair bit of data and I'm ordering by the results of these joins. I realise that each time I page it has to call the entire query again (to ensure correct ordering).

What I would like (without pulling entire result set into the client code and paging there) is that once it SQL Server got the whole result set it could then page through *that*

Is there any built-in way to achieve that? - I thought that views might do this but I can't find info on this.

EDIT: Indexed Views will not work for me as I need to pass in parameters.  Anyone got any more ideas - I think either I have to use memcached or have a service that builds indexes in the background.  I just wish there was a way for SQL Server to get that table and hold onto it whilst it is paged...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not very familiar with paging, and without knowing the logic behind your procedure, I can only guess you'd benefit from IndexedViews or #TemporaryTables with Indexes.

You mentionned you were ordering by a non-indexed field that is generated, that information combined with the fact that your procedure calls the entire query every time would lead me to believe you could make that query an IndexedView. You'd get better performance from accessing it multiple times and it would also enable you to add an Index onto the field you're ordering by.

You could also use a #TemporaryTable if it somehow stays alive during your paging requests... Insert the dataset you are working with in a #TemporaryTable, you can then create an index with T-SQL on the generated colum.

Indexed Views for SQL Server 2005: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc917715.aspx

Comment: Thanks very much - I'm going to look at this now as I think you are right - I will report back

Comment: Have battled with my massive query for ages and got it to create a view but now realise I cannot pass in any parameters...

Comment: What are the parameters used for and what do they represent?

Comment: They are a user id.  If I don't have that then I'm basically doing an n+1 select which takes way to long to process.

Comment: You can use the view just like a normal table, if it's just a column you need to match to the userid, simply SELECT * FROM MyView Where userid = @userid. You can also join other tables to it, all the normal table stuff.

Comment: Ok thanks PeekaySwitch - I will give it a go and see what happens!

Comment: thanks for your advice but in this case it didn't work out for me because of the number of subjoins I'm doing that rely on a parameter.  I think your answer is still very useful though so I'm going to accept it.